# How to get the text from an input()?

Tags: python

Explanation:
What I mean by "text", is the text inside an input.

Example of what I want:

```py
ipt = input("This is some input text")
print(ipt.value)
# returns "This is some input text"
```

Is this possible? And if so, how?

Edit:
The reason I want this is that the input text is dynamic.

Comment: I feel like this is an XY problem. Why not save "This is some text" to a variable _then_ pass it to `input`? That way you _already_ have a copy of the "text".

Comment: Why would you call `input()` if you already know the text you want to use?  What does `"This is some input text" ` have to do with what the user will enter?  Maybe I don't understand what you're asking.  What I think you're asking makes no sense to me.

Comment: What you're calling the text is called the *prompt*. The prompt is not saved anywhere, there's no way to get it.

Comment: The string that's returned from `input()` is just a regular string, it doesn't contain anything that indicates where it came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need the exact behavior you're demonstrating, but you could get the behavior if you wanted it by implementing your own version of the `input()` function.  Something like this:

```
class InputResult:
    def __init__(self, value, entered_text):
        self.value = value
        self.entered_text = entered_text

def myinput(prompt):
    return InputResult(prompt, input(prompt))

ipt = myinput("This is some input text")
print(ipt.value)
```

Value printed:

```
This is some input text
```

and if you want the text that the user entered, that's just `ipt.entered_text`.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in function `input` returns a string containing the input of the user.
You can check its documentation [here.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)

As Gino Mempin said, you can just store "This is some text" in a variable and pass it to `input`, or you can create your own custom `input` function

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Foo:
    value: str
    text: str
    
def custom_input(prompt: str) -> Foo:
    text = input(prompt)
    
    return Foo(prompt, text)
```

You can check the documentation for `dataclass` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)

Then, you will be able to do this:

```
ipt = custom_input("This is some input text")
print(ipt.value)
```